# How to do Google Drive authentication in JAVA?

Tags: java

I am creating a java desktop app for Linux environment (environment does not have gnome library) in which I need to implement google drive so that I can backup my files and upload them on google drive.

> The problem is whenever the authentication process is started the app
>   wants to open a browser for credential store
>
> but my app gives exception as  that Linux environment don't have gnome
>
> Exception:- can't load gnome lib

So, is there any process by which we can do google drive authentication without the browser. Please help

Comment: welcome to SO. please follow this link to ask proper question: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Your problem seems to have nothing to do with Google drive... It seems to be the way you open a browser. Could you explain how do you open your browser ? Cause in this operation you seem to call a gnome lib

Comment: JavaFX has WebView, you can use that for authentication.

Comment: @vincrichaud I am simply following the steps from  "https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java" and it auto opens browser . My code is working in windows and it uploads file on google drive but having issue in linux

Comment: @SahilManchanda I will try that, Thank you for the suggestion :)